# How can I configure the iPhone to send/receive mail through Gmail, but using a different e-mail address?

Tags: iphone, email, gmail, imap

I have a pobox.com account whose address I use as my main e-mail address and that forwards my messages to a Gmail address.

Eventough that is the address I tell my friends and coleagues, when I send e-mail from my iPhone it uses the default gmail.com address, and so people start to pick that as my e-mail address.

How should I configure a Gmail account in the iPhone that uses my pobox.com address for sent messages, instead of the gmail.com address? How should I set up storage of sent/junk/trash messages? How will Gmail archiving work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://groups.google.com/group/Gmail-Help-Gmail-for-Mobile-en/browse_thread/thread/b2ef777ac806bce6?pli=1) worked for me

> Assuming you have already setup the alternate account in your gmail
>
> - Remove the gmail account from your iphone
> - Add new mail account
>
>   - Settings > Mail > Add Account > Other
>   - Enter standard gmail id and password in New Account screen
>   - Enter standard gmail id and password in IMAP and SMTP screens (imap.gmail.com, smtp.gmail.com)
>   - After account is setup, under "IMAP Account Information" change address field to the desired account (Note that the "Incoming Mail Server" settings will remain as 
>       gmail info, this is the difference between creating the account manually and using the automatic gmail setup)
>
> Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

I've found a nice step-through, and it does what I need, but messages I delete in my iPhone continue appearing in the Gmail Inbox in the browser because the "inbox" label isn't removed.

http://5thirtyone.com/apple/how-to-proper-gmail-imap-for-iphone-apple-mail/